# AND operator in MongoDb Not retrieving proper data when Querying with ObjectId

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, embedded-documents

I'm trying to retrieve documents which can satisfy all the conditions in this query from a embedded document in an array.It's retrieving documents of any of the condition satisfied.

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find(
    { $and: [{ "users.type" : "user" },
       { "users.status" : "2"},
       {"users.userId" : ObjectId("Some Object Id")} ]}
```

Comment: So what's the problem in the above query???

Comment: I'm not getting proper Data from the query, even if the given conditions are not satisfied, it's retrieving all the doccuments with the any of the given conditions.

Comment: By guess is that problem is with the last condition `ObjectId("Some Id")`. Try without ObjectId

Comment: Thank You, query without objectId is working fine, but in my condition i have to filter data with the ObjectId. How can I filter with the Id?

Comment: Why it's not querying with the ObjectId??